# KNapsack variant. Ideas?

Tags: algorithm, math, knapsack-problem

I have the following knapsack problem variant:

I want to buy X units of a product at min cost, and there are m farmers that offer:
- [image]

and I can choose at most one option from each farmer.

Formally, I want to

[image]

Could you please let me know if this problem resembles a variant of 0-1 knapsack problem?

I would be grateful if you could provide any references where I can find more information about this or any relevant algorithms.

Comment: It would be great if you could let me know why you give negative points to this post!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can relate this to those (0-1 Knapsack) kind of problems. here also you will have to select one  option (the max number of units) from a farmer, possibly the one having the least cost/unit ratio, and then call the programm recursively, this time having one less farmer (the one from which the items are chosen from) the last time.

Comment: Thanks ralph. But this solution will end up to the brute-force approach? I would like to find a close-to polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: @STiGMa
you are talking about an np-complete problem. there are million dollar prizes for anyone who can come up with a polynomial time algorithm for these.

Comment: Indeed. I mean an FPTAS (fully polynomial time approximation scheme) algorithm.

Comment: @STiGMa
i am not well versed with FPTAS, cant figure out if this can be done to your problem. sorry.